# wkhtmltopdf ignores height set on html table, always overflows through footer

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf to convert an html file into a pdf.  My html file has a header div, a main body div with a table inside, and a footer div.  Inside the main body div is a table that is too big to fit on one page.

I want the resulting pdf to have a header, body and footer on each page, and if the table inside the body overflows, I want it to stop before the footer and continue on the next page.

Currently, no matter what css or settings I use, I cannot get wkhtmltopdf to obey a height on the table and restrain the size of what gets printed on each page.  It always prints the table all the way to the bottom edge of the first page, running right through the footer, and then onto the next page.

I am going to paste a screenshot here to help describe what is currently happening.  Below that, I will describe the things I have tried.

In the image, the pink/red rectangle represents the table inside the main body div.  You can see it runs right through the footer on the first page and continues onto the second page.  I want it to stop outputting before the footer and then continue on the next page.  The green marks the area I want the table to occupy, the portion of the html I am trying to restrict the height of.

[image]

Things I have tried:

- setting height, min-height, max-height on the main body div.  This DOES set the height of this container, but the table still flows out of it.
- setting height, min-height, max-height as css on the table inside the main body div.  This is ignored.
- setting the table height="" value right on the table, old school html style... this is ignored.
- setting overflow hidden on the main body div and using various css settings for page-break on main body and the table, but nothing has worked.
- tried on wkhtmltopdf versions 0.12.5 and on the newest 0.12.6

Helpful information:

- on the command line, I am using the following options: --enable-local-file-access --margin-top 6.35mm --margin-bottom 6.35mm --margin-left 6.35mm --margin-right 6.35mm --orientation landscape --disable-smart-shrinking --page-width 210mm --page-height 279mm

QUESTION: does anyone know how I can get wkhtmltopdf to obey the height I want it to use?  or know of a bug that causes this behavior?